# Why did this Rabbit behave like this?

Tags: zoology

https://youtu.be/B3_S3Uj18G8

In this video, inappropriately titled autistic rabbit, we see the rabbit first lying motionless before suddenly starting to spin around and jumping around.

What caused it to behave this way? Is it suffering from a disease?

I'm sorry if this is off topic. Please direct me to the appropriate site if it is.

Comment: Your question may be on-topic but since the video is not a part of a carefully designed scientific study it is almost impossible to conclusively say anything about the rabbit's behavior.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Your point is correct. Any conclusions would ultimately be impossible to conclusively verify. I was hoping that someone could lead me into the right direction so I could do the further research myself.

Comment: Doesn't look like voluntary movements. Probably some brain damage. Could be caused by lots of things...

Comment: Almost certainly diseased or injured.  The initial lunge seemed to be towards the person, and then there were frenzied but partially paralyzed movements. To my untutored eye this suggests it might be rabies, which can affect most any mammal, though seldom noted as occurring in rabbits.  (see [Rabies in Animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabies_in_animals))